# How to expiate for too many oath if someone cant keep fast or charity?is one expiation enough?

Tags: kaffarah

- List item

*emphasized text*is one expiation enough for too many oath?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your post: First there's no question asked in question section (see [ask]). Secondly, did you check the site for similar question?